# RegisterController Create method redirect with error message issue in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Redirect user to register page with error message user already exists.

**The thing is I cant use validation as type email because I am adding organization name manually @organization.com in the create code and I prevent users from entering @organization-name.com . Currently validation just checks if email value is filled. Therefore I need some strategy in create method to find out if email exists or not and take appropriate action here redirect back with error or redirect to login page saying user exists**

## This is my code in Register Controller - Create method

```
public function create(array $data)
{   

    $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
    $lastname  = Input::get('lastname');
    $username     = Input::get('email');
    $email = $username."@hw.ac.uk";
    //I need to do a check if this new user exists or not. 
    //If not go to Login page saying message user exists.
    $digits = 5;
    $new_code = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);

    $user = new User;
    $user->firstname             = $firstname;
    $user->lastname              = $lastname;
    $user->email                 = $email;
    $pswd                         = bcrypt(Input::get('password'));
    $user->password              = $pswd;

}
```

}

```
but when I register new user for the first time and re-register the same user with all different info but same email address. I get this error:

    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (...))

I know its a duplicate entry but I want to redirect user to login page and tell that user already exists with this email. How do I do that?
```

I used this:

```
$existing = User::select('email')->where('email',$email)->pluck('email');
        if($existing[0] == $email){

            return Redirect()->back()->withErrors('User already exists');
        }else{
            //continue
        }
```

But I get session guard error.

Comment: seems that your validator passes, otherwise no sql exception would be thrown

Answer (score 2):

The exception you get is for adding a new user with same email (which is unique as per your migrations). Before creating the `user` you can first check If it already exists or not.

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', 'user_email')->first();
if($user == null)
{
  //Add new user
}else { 
 return redirect()->route('someroute');
}
```

Comment: @Nauman Zafar Inside if condition of validator->fails I added redirect back withErrors ($validator) like we do other Controllers. I get this : Call to a member function validate() on null in RegistersUsers.php line 31.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia, Can you please post your complete code. More specifically what you are getting in `data` ?

Comment: `dd($data)` in your validator method and share what you get. That seems to be an issue. You `data` might be null.

Comment: @NaumanZafar No I got the data. array:14 [▼
  "_token" => "nOiPYe8aLqT8QRM1MH3b01Le8imsAoK8IntKo1Ip"
  "firstname" => "efdd"
  "lastname" => "hkdf"
  "email" => "jo185"
  "password" => "123123"
  "password_confirmation" => "123123"
  "campus" => "1"
  "schools" => "1"
  "years" => "1"
  "bio" => null
  "native_lang" => "4"
  "other" => null
  "flag_selected" => null
  "submit" => "Submit"
]

Comment: @NaumanZafar all I am looking for is that if user already exists with X email then simply redirect to login page with a msg user exists already. I want to avoid validation in Register Controller

Comment: Although, you are trying to avoid `validation` laravel provides. It is not recommended. Even If you have to check for uniqueness of your email you have to do `$user = User::where('email' , '=' , 'user_email')->first()`. And check if `$user` is not null this means user already exists and you can simply redirect.

Comment: @NaumanZafar I found the issue the thing is the problem is not in validation but in create method where I am inserting the user that already exists. if you can edit your answer to redirect from create method to register page with error message I can accept the answer. I am updating the question

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia, I have updated the answer. You can accept the answer.

Comment: @NaumanZafar this wont work in RegisterController I want a redirect method in RegisterController. I tried it throws this error just like other redirects : ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 408:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\Users\murli\laravel\E-Commerce-Web-App-published\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35 and defined